# Is it a good idea to change the learning rate at each training step as a function of the loss?

Tags: machine-learning, learning-rate

Is it a good idea to change the learning rate at each training step as a function of the loss? i.e. for points with high loss value, put a high learning rate and for low loss value a low learning rate (using a tailored function)?

I know that the update of the parameters is done via $\gamma \nabla L$, where $\nabla L$ is the gradient and $\gamma$ the learning rate, and that points with high loss should correspond to a high gradient. Hence the dependency of the update of the parameters on the value of the loss should be already contained, although in a more indirect way. Is doing what I propose dangerous and/or useless?

Comment: Have you ever heard of _adaptive learning rate_? I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but I've never read of a learning rate scheduler that updates the learning rate explicitly depending on the value of the loss at each step. Usually, for example, you halven the learning rate at a plateau, or something similar. I want to change the learning rate at each step

Comment: When you adjust your learning rate based on the loss, you have more chance to get stuck in local minima more often. It could be more efficient, but in general, I don't feel it has a positive effect in more complex situations.

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-rate-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/ maybe this is a good resource to go to.

Comment: Why you think you have more chances of getting a local minima? experience?

Comment: @JuliaOrtali Yes, but also from a theoretical point of view perhaps. I'm not saying it is always the case, but many times, losses around the minima are quite small, so the result will be that you keep taking smaller steps and eventually will never escape them. I do think that adapting your learning rate in a 'smarter' way will help. That's why optimizers like Adam and RMSprops are used more often instead of GD.So I guess that when adapting your learning rate for better outcomes will eventually lead you to an Adam optimizer.

Comment: its an interesting idea, but i dont see an obvious implementation. these very clever variations of vanilla backprop usually involve an "obvious formulation", such as SGD's loss function, or the update value for Newton's method of optimization. i dont see an obvious way of changing the learning rate asides from what is already implicit in the standard formulation, but it can be open to formulation

Comment: but as always, perhaps the best way to test this hypothesis is by testing it on somthing like MNIST